# Is it possible to add a specific Bluetooth LE device address to the advertisement filter using windows Bluetooth API?

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher

I start the advertisement watcher by filtering specific company Id. After that, I received advertisements from the device with this company Id, and I could get the Bluetooth address from BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs. I want to pick a specific Bluetooth address from the advertisements and restart the advertisement watcher for that specific Bluetooth address. I did not find any API from windows Bluetooth to filter a specific Bluetooth address. Is there any workaround to filter a specific Bluetooth address?

Comment: Sure. Just ignore any advertisements that received from other devices in your BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs

Comment: This is not a workable situation for me. In active scanning mode, the response sends automatically whenever an advertisement is received. That means other devices can get the advertisement and sends a response accordingly. I want to prevent that. That is why I would like to filter advertisement with Bluetooth address so that I could receive the advertisement only from that specific device.

Comment: Even if there could be such filter Windows will do exactly the same internally.

Comment: Windows will do that internally, but the acknowledgment only sends to a specific filter device address, not all the devices.

Comment: Ok, let it be so. Looks like you developed Windows BLE driver so you know it better.

Comment: I do not know. I am just trying to know. I should add a question mark, sorry. So, you are saying even if there is an API to filter Bluetooth address, windows will send the acknowledgment internally to all the devices it received the signal from? If so, is there any way to handle acknowledgment? So, that I could send the acknowledgment to a specific device instead of all the devices.

Comment: Yes, Windows API filtering (let say by UUID) implemented so that it does not notify driver about any filters. At least in current implementation. And Bt driver has not been changed for a long time (even new API was added). So the only way to filter devices is to filter it in your application. And yes, Windows will send ACK to all found devices in Active scan mode.

Comment: By the way, why do not simple run passive scan? As you know enough about your device you can get all the information from ATT if needed.

Comment: The device went to sleep mode when it received an acknowledgment. For that, we have to do this in active scanning mode.
Currently, the device communicates through a USB dongle. We are trying to replace that dongle communication with windows API. Writing to the device(a specific code for pairing) is possible through a specific attribute value, but I did not find that attribute value using Gatt services. Is there any API to change the attribute value of the Gatt services?

Comment: I didn't get it. If you write to the attribute's value - it has that attribute. So if it has the attribute it can be accessed through GATT.

Comment: Let's say for a specific GATT characteristics service UUID. I am reading from the GATT properties it's writable, but I am getting access denied when writing something. In the device description, I saw that writing could only be allowed through attribute handle 21, but from the GATT, I am reading attribute handle 20.

Comment: ATT handle 21 is the handle of the value. Characteristic has handle 20. If you got access denied you have to pair with your device and/or (depending on API) specify write flags (authentication.encryption). You can run GattClient demo app from our Bluetooth Framework (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm) and check out all the attributes and values (with handles). You can also test pairing with device. Here is the demo/test app: https://github.com/btframework/GattAuth (it supports BlueSoleil, Microsoft and BLED112 for BLE).

Comment: The device is paired, but writing access is denied. I tested your framework, and the result is the same. With your Framework, I got connect error: 0x0005105C. The device is not encrypted. I do not know why the access is denied. Using the "ERF Connect" android app from "silicon labs," I tested the device, and in the app, it's showing non-connectable.

Comment: The error indicates that device was not found. Unpair your device. Discover it, connect to it and try to read services and characteristics.

Comment: For the specific characteristic, your GattClient showing the device is readable only. But this characteristic has both read and write properties.

Comment: It it shows that the char is read only then it is read only. Probably your device is not configured correctly or (that looks more realistic from what you wrote above) your device needs authentication and then it opens the char for write. So once you connected tpo the device keep it connected, pair with it and then re-read characteristics. Use Read From Device flag so Windows resets the cache.